# Can I disable the auto power off on my Nikon SU-800

Tags: nikon, flash

Can I disable the auto power off on my Nikon SU-800 so it stays on for longer?
I need to use it in a different way.

Comment: You might want to ask the more specific question related to what you want to do, and why you think this setting might help.

Answer (score 1):

SU-800 go automatically in standby mode in two cases:

> The SU-800’s auto power-off function and camera’s  exposure meter-off
> function
>
> With a camera body that is compatible wi th TTL auto flash,
> the SU-800 goes into  standby mode when the camera’s exposure meter
> turns off. Without a camera body, if the SU-800 is not being used for
> approx. 40 seconds,  the standby function activates and automatically
> turns the SU-800 off to  conserve battery power. •  No indicators are
> displayed on the LCD panel in standby mode. •  When in standby mode or
> when the exposure meter is off, the SU-800 comes back on  again when:
> The [ON/OFF] button on the SU-800 is pressed. The camera’s power is
> turned on

I did not find any way to change this behavior
Reference [SU-800 manual](http://download.nikonimglib.com/archive2/fjsSS00dnTJB02EH9Pd005z9n144/SB-R200_EU(En)10.pdf), page 57